# Adding cooldowns to discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been researching methods to add cooldowns to only specific commands in my bot. I am unable to find anything that works, and I'm unsure how `@commands.cooldown(rate=1, per=5, bucket=commands.BucketType.user)` would be implemented into this code.

```
import discord
import random
from pathlib import Path
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('#help'):
        *command goes here*

    if message.content.startswith('#gamble'):
        *command goes here*

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Cooldowns only work with the `commands` extension

Comment: Your functions are `@client.event` which tell the bot to listen to specific events in Discord. You can't add a cooldown to events; they happen when they happen. Instead, cooldowns are used for commands, as another commenter suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using `commands.Bot` as it has all the functionality that `discord.Client` has + a full command system, your code rewrited would look like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
# You should enable some intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help") # Removing the default help command

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx): # Commands take a `commands.Context` instance as the first argument
    # ...

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 6.0, commands.BucketType.user)
async def gamble(ctx):
    # ...

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Take a look at the [introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)