# How would i add cooldown on my discord bot using python

Tags: python

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel('channel ID')
    if message.guild is None and message.author != client.user:
        await message.channel.send('Hi')   

client.run(<TOKEN>)
```

This is my code how would i add cooldown i want to make a bot that auto reply when another user dm

Comment: REMOVE THE BOT TOKEN! You are supposed to keep that a secret, otherwise everyone can create a bot and pretend it is yours. "We have logged in as T U N G#4887"

Comment: Thx i forgot about it

Comment: What do you mean by cooldown? is it the time between the bot can respond to messages? (ex: if a user sends a msg you want the bot to respond and then wait a certain amount of time before being able to respond again?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python possible duplicate

Comment: @Astros Yeah i want to make a cooldown that when user sends a message and my bot respond and then wait 30 minute to respond again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use the decorator

```
# cooldown(rate, per, type=<BucketType.default: 0>)
@command.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
```

This will limit 1 use per 30 seconds per user. [reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cooldown#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)

Comment: Where do I have to put it?

Comment: @client.event

@command.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)

async def on_message(message):

Comment: Got error "NameError: name 'command' is not defined"

Comment: You should import `from discord.ext import commands`

Comment: I think this may help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65753439/10956192

Comment: I think it is for @bot.command() not @@client.event